# Почему не работает цикл while?

Tags: c++, arduino, while

Провожу эксперименты с Arduino и решил замучать цикл while (вместо loop). Задал условие, при котором должен срабатывать цикл, но вместо срабатывания светодиод просто загорается и всё. Вот код:

```
int main() {

  int i = 0;

  DDRB = B00100000;

  while (i < 200)
  {
    PORTB |= B00100000;
    delay(1000);
    PORTB &= B00000000;
    delay(1000);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Может я туплю, или у компилятора мозги поплыли?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что весь ваш комплект ничего не знает о main...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вчёра он знал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл `while()` работает, в данном случае не работает `delay()`, а чтобы оный заработал (как и прочие подобные arduino'вские функции) надо сначала инициализировать саму arduino'вскую библиотеку с помощью `init()`.

```
int main() {
  int i = 0;

  init();

  DDRB = B00100000;

  while (i < 200)
  {
    PORTB |= B00100000;
    delay(1000);
    PORTB &= ~B00100000;
    delay(1000);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Альтернативой будет написать свою реализацию `delay()` с использованием активного ожидания или же таймера.

ЗЫ: К данной проблеме не относится, но если уж чисто включаешь пин, то стоит его так же чисто и выключать:

```
    PORTB &= ~B00100000;
```

Comment: Не работает( инит вроде бы сначала помог, но затем эта проблема вернулась

Comment: с ардуиновским delay заработало, но с delay'ем из `#include <util/delay.h>` работает не правильно - загорелся, подождал секунду, потух и на этом всё, хотя это цикл...

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich, УМВР, функция зовётся `_delay_ms()`

Comment: @Fat-Zet. Спасибо!

Comment: а почему не просто `&=`, а `&= ~`? `~` инвентирует - было `B00100000`, а стало `B11011111` -- Это как то не правильно...

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich, да, так и должно быть, побитовое И с единичным битом не изменяет изначальное значение, а с нулём сбрасывает его. таким образом всё выражение сбросит только **один бит**, но **не тронет значение остальных**. В Исходном варианте `&=0x00` вообще не имеет смысла и по факту равносильно обычному присваиванию нуля... ЗЫ: если вопрос закрыт, стоит отметить решённым дабы он не попадался на глаза...

Answer (score -1):

Работать напрямую с регистрами порта - не очень хорошая идея.

Попробуйте сделать через функции: **pinMode**, **digitalWrite**

Comment: А ничего, что от этого больше памяти съедается?

Comment: Ну да. Программа-то огромадная. Каждый бит на счету.

Comment: + проблема остаётся

Comment: Проблема осталась. Даже если поменять всё на pinMode, digitalWrite.

Comment: Работать с портами вместо тормозных digitalWrite - хорошая идея

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ++ Вы правы. Но я так и не понял, что с циклом?!

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich а если делать без цикла? Т.е. просто включить - delay - выключить?

Comment: @newman Всё ровно не работает(

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich значит дело не в цикле. Надо проверять что указывается нужный порт и нужный разряд. И что сведодиод управляется через порт. Кстати светодиод вообще не сам по себе загораяется?

Comment: @newman Порт точно нужный. Нее, светодиод сам не загорается.

Comment: Ауу, кто мне поможет?